# Is there a general word for inhaling and exhaling ? Something like ''haling'' or ''halation''?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm looking for a word that includes both inhaling and exhaling that derives from the same ''halare'' origin.

The word ''breathing'' obviously does the job but I'm wondering if other words exist such as a verb ''to hale/haling''  or as a noun ''halation'' etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

**halation** exists

OED

> n. 1. Photography. A halo-like effect in which light spreads beyond the edges of a bright object in a photograph.

**Haling** exists:

OED

> **hale**, v.1
>
> Now chiefly superseded by haul v.
>
> **1.a. transitive. To draw or pull (a person or thing) along, or from one place to another, esp. with force or violence; to drag, tug. Frequently with adverb or prepositional complement.**

The word is

OED

> **respiration**, n. 1.a. The action of taking air into the lungs (or water into the gills) and expelling it again, esp. as a continuous physiological process; breathing;

As far as I can see there is no English verb that uses the Latin root verb *hālāre* to indicate "breathing". There was one in Middle English "anhele" but that related to puffing and panting.

Comment: There is a verb related to _respiration_ though. It is [to respire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respire) as verified by Merriam Webster under the above link. This has the present continuous form _respiring_.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, but neither respiration nor respire qualify under the OP's condition *I'm looking for a word ... that derives from the same ''halere'' origin*, and it is unclear as to whether the OP wants a noun or a verb or a gerund.

Comment: @Greybeard All conjugations are welcome.

Comment: @Greybeard You are completely correct. I shouldn't try to write on both sides of the paper at once!